# PHP empty json string array

Tags: php, html

I am having a empty json string in my array. Would appreciate if anyone can assist here. thanks.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE country='singapore' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 $country = $row['country'];
 $lat = $row['lat'];
 $long = $row['long'];
 $array = array($country ,$lat, $long);
 foreach ($array as $value) 
 {

 $array[] = $value;

 } 
 $value = '[{"id":"36","latitude":"'.$array[1].'","longitude":"'.$array[2].'","username":"User Name 1","country":"Srbija","city":"'.$array[3].'","cityPart":"Grbavica","street":"","price":"200","area":"40","images":"img\/testimg.png[split]img\/testimg.png[split]img\/testimg.png","furniture":"Yes"}]'."<br>"."<br>";

}

$db = json_decode($value, true);

for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($db); $i++)
    {
    print_r ($data = $db[$i]);
    }
```

Comment: line 15 of `$value = ...` looks weird. What are you trying to achieve here in the whole code block?

Comment: There are A LOT of issues here, but your `json` issue is probably caused by the `."<br>"."<br>"` at the end of `$value` as it makes it invalid `json`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I remove ."<br>"."<br>" and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your $value json line seems to be an issue.

I'd suggest you to define an array first and then json_encode it.

But one thing that needs to be clarified is what's the use of json format in the first place? Is the json needed in somewhere else? If not, I don't see a point in json encoding and decoding unnecessarily.